# Can I use a 'byte' for boolean array?

Tags: java, mysql, swift

In an app we're making (iOS/Swift, Android), we're having a settings-page for when the user wants to receive push notifications. One of the settings is for the user to select which days of the week.

My question is regarding how to store this option as one variable, rather than seven booleans. The setting will be sent to a server/database to be stored, and I was thinking we could simply use a single byte-field in a database.
Rather than `monday=true, tuesday=false, ...`, I would like to use e.g '10001010' where 1 is true and 0 is false, which would translate to `monday=true(1), tuesday=false(0), etc` (given monday is the first day of the week, which it is..).

Is this a valid way to store such data? Can I create a byte like that? Or is it a more used practice to use a string/char[] "10001010"? Or can databases (eg. MySQL) store bool[] (10001010) as one field? Or is there another, better practice for this?
The method used for permissions also came to mind (you know, 777, just simplified)

Of course, some variations would require the server to use the same logic for the variable, but that's no problem in this case.

Short explanation, I need seven booleans, one for each day of the week, and I want to store it more efficiently than one variable per day. Is there a 'best practice'?

Comment: consider a [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)

Comment: From a memory point of view using a byte or bitset for 7 booleans would probably the way to go, from a maintainance point of view I'd probably use something easier to read, e.g. a string like `1010000` or `x-x----`. If the database column doesn't need to support more than basic crud functionality (e.g. no sorting, no joins on those columns, etc.) you could also save the settings as a JSON string etc.

Comment: *"Is there a 'best practice'?"* - Yes.  Best practice is to understand the pros and cons yourself, and apply that knowledge to the problem.  Best practice is to not ask if there is a 'best practice'!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question "shreaks"  premature optimization:

- The space occupied by 7 boolean variables is negligible (probably 7 x 4 bytes) ... unless you need to hold hundreds of thousands of user settings objects in memory at the same time.
- The difference in network bandwidth is negligible ... unless you are sending millions of messages.
- The difference in database table space is negligible ... unless you are storing millions of user records in the database.

---

> Is this a valid way to store such data?

Define "valid".  But yes it works (mostly).

> I want to store it more efficiently than one variable per day

Yes ... but is it necessary to do that?  Have you quantified how much you might gain by this (supposed) efficiency.

---

For what it is worth, there are a number of penalties for packing multiple booleans into a byte / word / whatever.  These include:

- Access and update of a flags packed into a single variable involves additional bitwise operations, which tends to make things slower.
- Representing flags as bits in the database is going to make SQL queries more difficult, depending on the database.  (See http://blog.jooq.org/2011/10/30/the-comprehensive-sql-bitwise-operations-compatibility-list/).  It may also interfere with query optimization.
- Readability.

Comment: The other answers here gave me what I asked for, but you gave me more! Your note on SQL query penalty was something I hadn't thought of, and sounds quite correct. There will queries to select fields e.g `where monday=true`, which I agree could turn out to be a severe penalty when dealing with hundreds of thousands of rows on that query alone. This is the correct answer for me. However, to other users to whom the question is still valid, I suggest looking at the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it like that.

```
class A {
    public static final int MONDAY = 0;
    ...
    public static final int SUNDAY = 6;

    // call with the above defined constants for day
    public byte addDay(byte b, int day) {
        return (byte) (b | (1 << day));
    }

    public boolean isDaySet(byte b, int day) {
        return ((b >> day) & 1) == 1 ;
    }
}
```

This is of course just some quick and dirty example code, but I hope, it makes the concept clear.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Forgot to take it over from my IDE ;).

Answer (score 1):

Just do some bitwise operations on bytes. Example code

```
enum Days {
    MON,
    TUE,
    WED,
    THU,
    FRI,
    SAT,
    SUN
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    byte encode = (byte)0b1010000;

    for ( Days d : Days.values() ) {
        boolean present = (encode & 1<<d.ordinal()) != 0;
        System.out.println(d + " " + present);
    }

    System.out.println("Adding MON, removing SUN");

    encode |= (1<<Days.MON.ordinal());
    encode &= ~(1<<Days.SUN.ordinal());

    for ( Days d : Days.values() ) {
        boolean present = (encode & 1<<d.ordinal()) != 0;
        System.out.println(d + " " + present);
    }

}
```

Of course, you should wrap it into some nicer classes/accessor methods, maybe add a ready to use value directly into Days enum as field instead of using 1<

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an [EnumSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) like advised by Item 32 in Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java". (EnumSets are internally BitVectors)

Use `java.time.DayOfWeek` as enum type.

Days of week contained in the Set are the selected ones by your user. The others are not selected.

```
EnumSet<DayOfWeek> selectedDays = EnumSet.of(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY);

selectedDays.contains(DayOfWeek.MONDAY); // true
selectedDays.contains(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY); // false
```